How can I combine a list of objects var and a list of resources in terraform?
I have a variable with a list of load-balancer targets. Ports, health checks etc. Defined as follows (with some sane defaults):
variable "port_mappings" {
  type = list(object({
    containerPort = string
    hostPort = string
    lbPort = string
    host_tls = bool
    lb_tls = bool
    health_path = string
    health_interval = number
    unhealthy_threshold = number
    health_matcher = string
    create_before_destroy = bool
  }))
  default = [{
    containerPort = "8080"
    hostPort = "8080"
    lbPort = "443"
    host_tls = true
    lb_tls = true
    health_path = "/health"
    health_interval = 30
    unhealthy_threshold = 5
    health_matcher = "200-399"
    create_before_destroy = true
  }]
}

I then use that list of objects to create a list of resources like so:
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "this" {
  for_each    = var.port_mappings
  name        = "${var.environment}-${var.app_name}-http-${each.value.hostPort}"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
  protocol    = "TCP"
  port        = each.value.hostPort
  target_type = "ip"

  health_check {
    port                = "traffic-port"
    protocol            = each.value.host_tls ? "HTTPS" : "HTTP"
    path                = each.value.health_path
    interval            = each.value.health_interval
    unhealthy_threshold = each.value.unhealthy_threshold
    matcher             = each.value.health_matcher
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = each.value.create_before_destroy
  }
}

Next, I want to create an aws_lb_listener resource for each aws_lb_target_group, but I need value from both the list of objects (my var) and the list of aws_lb_target_group resources.
resource "aws_lb_listener" "this" {
  for_each = aws_lb_target_group.this
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.this.arn
  port              = **lbPort value from my list of objects var**
  protocol          = **ternary based on lb_tls bool from my list of objects var**
  certificate_arn   = aws_acm_certificate.this.arn

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = **target group from the list of aws_lb_target_group resources**
  }
}

What's the best way to go about this?

The code from the question (even the part for target group) will not work for multiple reasons:

The lifecycle block does not allow using variables, the value has to be known in advance, hence each.value.create_before_destroy will throw the following error:


create_before_destroy = each.value.create_before_destroy
│
│ Variables may not be used here.
create_before_destroy = each.value.create_before_destroy
│
│ Unsuitable value: value must be known


The way the variable is currently defined means it cannot be used with for_each:


The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of
│ type list of object.

Since that is the case, the first thing that needs to be fixed is the variable. Based on your question, I would suggest using a map and not a set type variable. You could construct the variable similar to the following:
variable "port_mappings" {
  type = map(object({
    container_port      = number
    lb_port             = number
    host_tls            = bool
    lb_tls              = bool
    health_path         = string
    health_interval     = number
    unhealthy_threshold = number
    health_matcher      = string
  }))
  description = "A map of objects to configure target groups."

  default = {
    "8080" = {
      container_port      = 8080
      health_interval     = 30
      health_matcher      = "200-399"
      health_path         = "/health"
      host_tls            = true
      lb_port             = 443
      lb_tls              = true
      unhealthy_threshold = 5
    }
  }
}

Where the key actually represents the host port for the target group. Then, for the listener resource, you can do the following:
resource "aws_lb_listener" "this" {
  for_each          = var.port_mappings
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.this.arn
  port              = each.value.lb_port
  protocol          = each.value.lb_tls ? "HTTPS" : "HTTP"
  certificate_arn   = each.value.lb_tls ? aws_acm_certificate.this.arn : null

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.this[each.key].arn
  }
}


Thank you. Unfortunately, protocol of the aws_lb_target_group.health_check block and protocol of the aws_lb_listener block are two slightly different things. The former is the protocol of the backend server/service (port_mappings.host_tls), whilst the latter is the protocol of the load-balancer VIP (portmappings.lb_tls). Oftentimes, these will both be HTTPS/TLS but sometimes may not be. Typically HTTPS to the loab-balancer but HTTP to backend. portmappings.lb_tls isn't used in the aws_lb_target_group resource.

I know they are different, I was just trying to give an answer that's the easiest to implement. :)
